# Why is my code blowing because of declaration of a static object with explicit constructor inside a function?

Tags: c++, gcc

When I declare a static object of class bar which has an explicit constructor in a function I get a lot of stdc++ library overhead that I don't expected (including exception handling despite -fno-exceptions)

```
class bar
{
  public:
    bar() { a=0; };    
  private:
    int a;
};

void func()
{
  static bar tbar;
}
```

If the constructor of bar is not explicit declared I don't get this overhead. I'm using gcc V4.5.2.

What's happening there?

Comment: First, you want to compile with full optimization. Second, make your ctor `noexcept`. Third, why not an updated gcc-version?

Comment: Did you try making your `ctor` `constexpr`? That should remove the dynamic initialization, and thus all the overhead.

Comment: Of course I enabled code optimization (-Os). An updated gcc-version will be nice but is no option because of corporate reasons.

Making the ctor constexpr makes no difference. But thanks for that hint.

Comment: In my test, `constexpr` makes all the difference: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb73b4598e9a7757 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1692f0e0f9236f18

Comment: `explicit` is a keyword: do not use it for a different concept when talking about C++ code.

Comment: Deduplicator's `noexcept` sounds worth a shot.  Failing that - bit more desperate - you could try defining the constructor like this `bar() : a(0) { }`, just to make sure your old compiler's optimiser doesn't give up for non-empty function bodies while handling initialiser lists for simple types.  Long shot though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What's your gcc version?

Do you have a example how to make my ctor noexcept? Why is the compiler including exception handling for my simple constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the Itanium C++ ABI I found out that the compiler tries to realize the guard variables for function-scope static variables threadsafe:

```
 if (obj_guard.first_byte == 0) {
    if ( __cxa_guard_acquire (&obj_guard) ) {
      try {
    ... initialize the object ...;
      } catch (...) {
        __cxa_guard_abort (&obj_guard);
        throw;
      }
      ... queue object destructor with __cxa_atexit() ...;
      __cxa_guard_release (&obj_guard);
    }
  }
```

For that reason exception handling etc. are included resulting to a vast increase of code size ... not acceptable for embedded projects. To disable this threadsafe behaviour use compiler option

> **-fno-threadsafe-statics**